# Showing top and current ranking in Stack Overflow - Profile tab

Tags: discussion, feature-request, reputation-leagues

Will it be a good idea to show our all time Highest and Current ranking from [User Reputation League](https://stackexchange.com/leagues/1/alltime/stackoverflow) like the below in our profile tab.

```
Highest ranking #40458 (11 Oct 2015)
Current ranking #44704
```

**Update:**

Few of them got confused with the term `Highest` rank. Hope `Top` is the correct term instead of `Highest`.

So the expected feature in the **Profile** tab is:

```
Top ranking     #40458 (11 Oct 2015)
Current ranking #44704
```

Comment: How can your highest ranking be below the current ranking? Wouldn't the current ranking be the highest in that case?

Comment: @Anthon: Okay, i updated the order.

Comment: @BillWoodger: If i was active in last year and scoring regularly and get the Rank #40458 and in the last 6 months i didn't involve in any activity, it's possible to reduce rank (#79458) right?

Comment: Yeah. Sorry. Reading upside down. Removing comments :-)

Comment: Currently you already see a stat from one of the leagues mentioned under your reputation in the activity tab. Why is it important for other members that visit your profile that those two specific numbers are visible?

Comment: @rene: About _Currently you already see a stat_,  it's not standard. Depends on your reputation (sometimes on recent activity) it shows **top 2% overall** or **top 4% this year** or **top 5% this month** or **top 3% this week**. About _Why is it important_, Frankly says i don't have a valid reason, but it helps to show our highly achieved ranks in our profile page always (we may active in particular period and earned good reputation and rank and later we may not active).